# Accidentally deleted GCP instance connected to AI notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I accidentally deleted my ai notebook vm and I hadn't downloaded the notebooks connected to it. I still have the url. Does anybody know if there's a way for me to recover my work?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, there is a [life cycle](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/instance-life-cycle) for the instances. Verify the state of your AI Notebook VM to make sure that it is deleted or just turned off.

Unfortunately, if an AI Notebook instance is deleted and there is no snapshot configured, there is no way to restore that instance neither recover the notebooks stored there. There are three ways to prevent this from happening in the future:

1. Create [snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) to periodically or schedule back up data from your [zonal persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#create_zonal_snapshot) (snapshot can be located in multiple zones) or [regional persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#create_regional_snapshot) (You must indicate the region where the disk is located ).
2. Edit VM instance, go to the [deletion protection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion#setting_deletion_protection_during_instance_creation) checkbox to enable it as this option is disabled by default. This setup will avoid that your Notebook instance was deleted by accident.
   [image]
3. In the VM instance, go to boot disk, in the drop down list under “When deleting instance” select **“Keep Disk”** (or you can use gcloud command to disable [set-disk-auto-delete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/set-disk-auto-delete))[image]